# Calculate the Size of a Set of Files

Tags: macos, bash, shell, command-line

Using a command-line tool (Mac OSX), how do I calculate the size of all *jpg* files in a particular directory e.g. `~/Pictures/`?

I know how to list those *jpg* files but have no clue how to count their combined size.

```
$ cd ~/Pictures/
$ find . -name '*.jpg'
# Help?
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run the files through `du` using `xargs`, like this:

```
find . -name "*html" -print0 | xargs -0  du -shc
```

Alternatively, turn on globstar in bash which allows you to use `**/` to match directories and subdirectories:

```
shopt -s globstar
du -shc **/*.jpg
```

(Note, the `-c` option on `du` produces a grand total.)

Comment: Looks like `xargs du -shc` fails when the input line contains spaces e.g. `./Photo Booth Library/Pictures/Photo on 2011-06-23 at 06.30.jpg`

Comment: Thank you and +1 (oopss, not enough privilege at this point)!

Comment: on OSX Mountain Lion `shopt -s globstar` results in "bash: shopt: globstar: invalid shell option name"

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about Mac OSX's `wc`, but it should be able to count the bytes:

```
shopt -s globstar
cat **/*.jpg | wc -c
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
 find . -name "*.jpg" -exec stat -c "%s" {} \; | paste -sd'+' | bc
```

Answer (score -1):

try with:

du --max-depth=1 -m

it list all files/folders in working directory with their total size in Megabytes...